# Android emulator on windows 8 Touch enabled deskptop/laptop

Tags: windows-8, android-emulator

I understand that for Multi-Touch support, we need to have a device in place for testing the Androind application.

In this context, I am wondering if I can do the testing of touch based actions on Android application through Android emulator which is running on a touch enabled Windows 8 laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an authority on the topic, but I have installed [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) and used Android apps with touch on Windows 8 without a problem. At least the basic testing can be done, but as to whether or not it's capable of doing refined or performance testing I'm not sure.